# For the birthday problem, what if a person was chosen beforehand?

Tags: probability, statistics, birthday

Referring to the "Discussion" section of the [following page](http://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter2/2_1_2_ordered_without_replacement.php), I wanted to know why
P(B) wasn't $\frac{(n-1)^{k-1}}{n^{k-1}}$. Note $k$ is the number of people at a party and $n=365$.

Because there is 1 less person to account for, we need only consider $n^{k-1}$ permutations of possible birthdays for everyone.

Of those permutations, there is 1 less birthday date since we are accounted for. So the number of dates that may be birthday dates without matching my birthday is $(n-1)$. Since there are $(k-1)$ people at the party, the first person may have their birthday fall on any $(n-1)$ day, the second on any $(n-2)$, ..., the $k$'th on any $(n-k)$ day.

So the total number of possibilities for $(k-1)$ people to not have the same birthday is: $(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k)$ = $P^{n-1}_{k-1}$

Comment: Which page [1]?

Comment: Your [linked page](http://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter2/2_1_2_ordered_without_replacement.php) looks wrong when it says *"I am in a party with $k−1$ people. What is the probability that at least one person in the party has the same birthday as mine? ... the probability that no one has the same birthday as mine is $P(B)=1-\left(\dfrac{n-1}{n}\right)^n$"* where $n=365$. I think you are right.  Or change the $k-1$ in the question to $k$ and the answer from *"no one"* to *"at least one"*. Probably typos.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'll take a shot at this.

If there are $n$ "days" and $k-1$ people (besides yourself) in the room, then the probability that somebody has the same birthday as you is:

$$ 1 - \frac{(n-1)^{k-1}}{n^{k-1}} = 1 - \left(1-\frac 1n\right)^{k-1}$$

The proof is simple, we start by counting the opposite: the probability that nobody has the same birthday as you. For any person, this probability is $1 - \frac 1n$, and since there are $k-1$ people and the events are independent we have:

$$ P(\text{nobody has the same birthday}) = \left(1-\frac 1n\right)^{k-1} $$

We **want the opposite of that event**. This is why we take the complement by doing $1 - $ the above, and gives the stated answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is independent here?

Comment: @MinhTran the event that a person does not have the same birthday as you. (If the $6$th person doesn't have the same birthday as you, that doesn't affect the chance that the $99$th person has the same birthday as you.) The probability is always $1 - \frac 1n$.